# ASP.NET MVC3 & JavaScript: How to get Intellisense on functions & variables located in other JS files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I have one JavaScript-file for each view and each partial view. So if I have the following files:

```
User.cshtml
User.js
_EditUser.cshtml
_EditUser.js
```

Now, I want to have intellisense in file '_EditUser.js' for functions and variables defined in 'User.js'. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
/// <reference path="User.js" />
```

to the top of _EditUser.js

Update:
To see more than names of variables and functions of User.js you need to add special comments with tags. They are like usual comments for documenting C# code in Visual Studio. One of minor differences is this comments are inside function body not before. You can see it in jQuery-with-doc-file as you mentioned in comment.

```
function Some(key, value)
{
   /// <summary>Function do some value with key</summary>
   /// <param name="key" type="String">Key argument</param>
   /// ... and so on ...

}
```

Comment: I already tried that one, didn't work. I guess, I have to do it like the jquery-doc-File...

Comment: Yes you need to document your vars and functions. But at least (with reference sign) you can see variables name and function signatures of User.js